# C# DataGridView opening ContextMenu at location of Right Click

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenu

I've looked around for quite a while now trying to find a working solution but am resorting to asking a question:

I have a DataGridView in a Dialog Form in my app, that I want a ContextMenu to appear on Right-Click of Cell.

I have the right-click and the ContextMenu appearing fine, however no matter what solution on StackExchange I attempt, it is always offset quite alot.

Is this to do with the form and/or it's parent? Or am I just stupidly missing something here?

Thanks
Jamie

**Form.cs**

```
private void dataGridContents_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Cell right clicked!");

            DataGridViewCell cell = (sender as DataGridView)[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

            contextCell.Show(cell.DataGridView, PointToClient(Cursor.Position));

            if (!cell.Selected)
            {
                cell.DataGridView.ClearSelection();
                cell.DataGridView.CurrentCell = cell;
                cell.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Sorry, I have tried:

- `new Point(e.X, e.Y)`
- `new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y)`
- `new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)`
- `PointToClient(e.X, e.Y)`
- `new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)`
- `Control.MousePosition`
- `Cursor.Position`

and probably a few others.

**Edit 2**

This is what I mean by offset -- some of the solutions cause this offset to vary in certain magnitudes (some really far away etc) -- but all are offset like those from the actual Cursor.

[image]

**Edit 3**

My `contextCell` is a `new ContextMenu()`

Comment: What do you mean by offset?  As in the context is not appearing where the cursor is?

Comment: I've edited a screenshot :) But yeah -- offset from the cursor is

Comment: If using a ContextMenuStrip, try `contextCell.Show(Cursor.Position);`

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech but also tried that (updated my OP) and it actually makes it worse -- about double the offset in the above screenshot :(

Comment: Use a ContextMenuStrip instead.

Comment: Yep! that was it lol -_- Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1:** The most simple solution for showing a context menu for rows is assigning the context menu to `RowTemplate.ContextMenuStrip` property of DataGridView:

```
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
```

**Option 2:** Also if you want to select the cell before showing the `ContextMenuStrip`, it's enough to handle `CellContextMenuStripNeeded` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContextMenuStripNeeded(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        e.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
    }
}
```

---

**What was your mistake?**

You are calculating the mouse position on the `DataGridView` in a wrong way. You are using `PointToClient` which means `this.PointToClient`, while you need to use the method of `DataGridView`, for example `dataGridView1.PointToClient`:

```
myContextMenu.Show(dataGridView1,dataGridView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
```

Just for your information you can simply show `ContextMenu` using this code and there is no need to use `ContextMenuStrip`.

But I strongly recommend you to use `ContextMenuStrip`.

Answer (score 1):

or

```
this.dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = this.contextMenuStrip1;
```

and handle the `DataGridView.CellContextMenuStripNeeded` [Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontextmenustripneeded)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to make `contextCell` a `ContextMenuStrip` instead of the `ContextMenu` it was.

After all that........

Thanks for responses.

Comment: I described what was your mistake. Read it in the answer :)

Comment: Yeah cool thanks-- the PointToClient method was just one of the ways I tried -- pretty sure did every method I could lol -- but the answer was only to make it a ContextMenuStrip instead of ContextMenu and attach that ContextMenuStrip to the DataGridView and then I didn't even need to set its location -- it worked fine straight away :)

Comment: It seems you didn't understand what I said in the answer. You can show also a `ContextMenu`. But you should use correct position. Your mistake was just passing incorrect position. Obviously you can show also a `ContextMenu` and using a `ContextMenuStrip` is not a must!

Comment: Ahhh, yes I see -- sorry wasn't reading it through -- I see what you mean about the referencing the dataGridView -- I didn't try that. All good -- problem solvered! :D