# Right-click to select DataGrid Row not working

Tags: c#, winforms, right-click

I've read a few questions asking how to achieve DataGridRow selection when there's a right-click on the grid. The answers show a few different ways to achieve it and, for most part, they've worked for me except for this weird bug.

The row appears to be selected but unless the row is left-clicked first, the first row is always the row selected when the action is chosen. i.e. When I click edit on row 3, row 1's data will be passed to the edit form (unless I left click row 3 before right-clicking it)

This is the right-click menu showing the apparent selection:

[image]

Notice the little indicator is still on the first row.

If I dismiss the context menu, the row looks selected but is not:

[image]

If I left-click the same row it is now selected

[image]

Here's the code for the right-click event:

Designer code:

```
MyDataGrid.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MyDataGridView_MouseDown);
```

Form code:

```
private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {       
        var hti = MyDataGrid.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        MyDataGrid.CurrentCell = MyDataGrid.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Cells[hti.ColumnIndex];
    }
}
```

What am I missing to actually select the row?

Comment: As an option you can simply assign a `ContextMenuStrip` to a row. Also if you want the row get selected before showing the menu, you can handle `CellContextMenuStripNeeded` event. It seems [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38510619/3110834) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code in the `MouseDown` event call back with this:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

        if (hti.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[hti.RowIndex].Cells[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a demonstration of it working:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the right clicked row the focused row in the `CellMouseDown` event like this

```
if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
{
     DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found I needed to add a check to make sure e.RowIndex and e.ColumnIndex are not -1 (what is returned if you click outside of the cell area, such as the headers)

Answer (score -1):

This is because right-click does not actually select the cell you've right-clicked on, only the left-click does this. You need to add a handler for the cell mouse down event, add this to your form's designer:

```
MyDataGridView.CellMouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.MyDataGridView_MouseDown);
```

And add this to your form's class:

```
private void MyDataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    MyDataGridView.CurrentCell = MyDataGridView(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
}
```

This will set the `CurrentCell` a.k.a. The cell that's currently selected to whichever cell the cursor was over when the `MouseDown` event was called.

Comment: you could add a check on right mouse clicked to this `if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)`

Comment: @GuidoG No because OP is using a handler for the DataGridView itself, not the cells within it

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  Always test it before posting.

Comment: @LarsTech it was a simple name mismatch, you could have just fixed my answer rather than just telling me I'm wrong. Now fixed.